# android LicenseValidator : Signature verification failed

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I'm having a problem with the LVL in one app.

We have around 10 Apps in that we are using License check, but today only one App is not working. Its showing Signature Verification Failed error. All 10 apps are using the same licensing library, apart from one app all are working perfectly fine. Not getting why its not working. The Key I'm using is definitely correct!

The error I get in logcat is:

```
12-12 15:22:07.000: E/LicenseValidator(6783): Signature verification failed.
```

And the dontAllow() function of the LicenseCheckerCallback is run.

I'm testing the apps on a Nexus One.

Comment: Have you found an answer, currently experiencing the same issue

Comment: Have somebody found an answer? I can't do it all day. Signature verification failed - and that's it. Signature string in response are always empty. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3):

1st, double check the `BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY` in the app against the Developer Console -> Development Tools -> Services & APIs Base-64 code.

2nd, do not change the `versionCode` in the gradle files until you are ready to "Build -> Generate Signed APK" and upload it to the store. Version codes that haven't been used in uploaded previous versions come back unlicensed.

3rd, make sure that the user, who is signed in on the device, does have a license (either real or tester).

4th, make sure that the internet connection works on the device.

Comment: I confirm that the 2nd was my case. Answer still correct in 04-2020. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that I changed the versionCode in my AndroidManifest file, but the new version was not know to the Google developer console. After uploading the new apk, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a bizarre solution but it worked for me:

I logged into the Android Developer Console, navigated to the Edit Profile screen, and reset my License Test Response to a different value. After saving, I reset the test response back to what it was before and saved again. After I did that, the error disappeared and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the test response stuff is very brittle. I've seen it reply with incorrect stuff, even when using StrictPolicy. This blog post mirrored my experience exactly:

- [Android License Test Response - Never Works](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=765)